# what should I do to capture the emulator error when starting flutter app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I start debugging the flutter (v3.0.5) app, when the app started to run in emulator(iPhone XR), the connection was suddenly closed and the android studio shows logs like this:

```
To see a detailed report, use the untranslated-messages-file 
option in the l10n.yaml file:
untranslated-messages-file: desiredFileName.txt
<other option>: <other selection> 


This will generate a JSON format file containing all messages that 
need to be translated.
Launching lib/main_pro.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           15.5s
Exception: Unable to launch com.earth.dolphin on 911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
com.earth.dolphin: -1

2022-07-30 22:38:44.693 simctl[49283:1455874] apply_selection_policy_once: avoid use of removable GPUs (via com.apple.CoreSimulator.simctl:GPUSelectionPolicy->avoidRemovable)
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "com.earth.dolphin" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace).
Underlying error (domain=FBProcessExit, code=128):
    The operation couldn’t be completed. The process exited.
    The process exited.
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl launch 911ED020-A317-4E0E-AA48-A2369DD9EED8 com.earth.dolphin --enable-dart-profiling --enable-checked-mode --verify-entry-points --start-paused --observatory-port=0
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

maybe the app encount an error when start to run, but from this error information, I could not figure out what's happen with the app in the emulator, is it possible to capture the exit error information from the ios emulator so that I could know where is going wrong? when I using xcode to debugging the app, just shows error:

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I could hardly known where is going wrong and what should I do fixed this problem. any way could fetch more clear log output?

Comment: Can you try this command: "flutter clean" inside your project folder.

Comment: I have already tried this command for many times. @igdmitrov

Comment: Try this: Apple logo -> About this Mac -> Storage -> Manage -> Developer -> Xcode caches and remove it.

Comment: Open the Xcode project that flutter creates and run your app from Xcode.